# WireShark in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, wireshark

I'm new in UNIX. I've installed WireShark on Ubuntu 12.04 and there is no interface list in Capture section. There is only  text "No interface can be used for capturing in this system with the current configuration". How can I configure system for capturing? I hope to see simple step by step tutorial.

Comment: @PedroRomano How can I migrate this question?

Comment: I've flagged it for moderator attention. Hopefully they'll take care of it. I am not sure if you have enough reputation to also flag it as off-topic. Otherwise you can always re-create the question on one of the other sites and delete it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add yourself to the 'wireshark' group to see the interfaces.

> useradd -G {group-name} username

Another alternative is running wireshark as root, but this is not recommended, as it can be exploited as an ivasion point to your PC.